# Check condition on each pandas DataFrame cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I have a pandas DataFrame *corr* which collects correlations between 2k variables. Since I didn't create it, I would like to check whether it satisfies the usual consistency properties of a correlation matrix (simmetry, all numeric values in [-1,1],no missing values,...). How can I check such conditions efficiently, since my actual code involves two nested loops?

For the sake of completeness I generate a df below with an example of my actual checks.

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.normal(size=(10000,2000)), columns = ["var"+str(i) for i in range(0,2000)])
corr = df.corr()

inconsistent_cells=[]
for row in corr.index:
      for col in corr.columns:
                value = corr.loc[row,col]
                if not isinstance(value,float) or (value<-1 or value>1):
                    inconsistent_cells.append((value, (row,col)))
```

I think one possible solution would be to use *itertuples()*, but then I would loose info about cell coordinates. The same is true for *apply()*.

Any suggestion is appreciate, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a custom function to check:

```
def check_df(df):
    #symmetry
    if not df.eq(df.T).all().all():
        return False
    #between -1 and 1
    if not df.apply(lambda x: x.between(-1,1,inclusive="both").all()).all():
        return False
    #null values
    if df.isnull().any().any():
        return False
    return True
```